# How to highlight or mark a line in vim

Tags: vim

We can highlight different marks in vim using mark.vim but, how can I highlight a line in Vim?

For example:

```
Line One
Line Two
Line Three
```

I let the cursor on line one, I highlight `line one`, the whole line is highlighted.
Then I type `jj` to move to line 3, the line one is highlighted too, but didn't disappear.

Comment: What do you mean by highlight?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813466/highlighting-arbitrary-lines-in-vim

Answer (score 6):

Use `v` to get into visual mode. `<shift>v` will highlight the entire line and `<ctrl>v` will take you into visual block mode so you can highlight columns.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for the permanent highlighting of the *current* line, following along with the cursor, that's a built-in feature of Vim since version 7.0. To activate this, put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set cursorline
```